# Converting nested loop into idiomatic Java 8 stream operators

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

The following legacy logic needs to be converted into Java 8 functional approach:

```
AchFile dataRoot = unmarshalled.stream().findFirst().get();
        
        List<AchBatch> batches = dataRoot.getBatchRecords();
        //batches.stream().flatMap(b -> b.getBatchEntries().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getBatchEntryDetails().stream().map(d -> d.setReceivingIndividualCompanyName("Client"))));
        
        for (AchBatch batch : batches) {
            int cntr = 1;
            for (AchBatchEntry entry : batch.getBatchEntries()) {
                Iterator<AchBatchEntryDetail> it = entry.getBatchEntryDetails().iterator();
                for (; it.hasNext(); cntr++ ) {
                    AchBatchEntryDetail detail = it.next();
                    detail.setReceivingIndividualCompanyName("Client Name"+cntr);
                    detail.setAmount(detail.getAmount());
                    
                    String maskedAccount = randomizeAccountNumber(detail);
                    
                    detail.setDfiAccountNumber(maskedAccount);
                    
                    log.info("Masked detail record #{}", cntr);
                }
            }
        }
```

What would be an equivalent and idiomatic Java 8 syntax of unwinding such nested loop structure?

I've started applying `flatMap` together with regular `map` operations (as can be seen in the commented out portion) but am not quite sure I'm on the right track and would appreciate some guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Streams aren't supposed to be applied *everywhere*. It is *especially* unsuitable if you are doing modifications in place, like what you are doing here. You *should not* change this code to use streams.

Comment: If you actually want to write code in a more "functional" way, you would make `AchBatch`, `AchBatchEntry` and `AchBatchEntryDetail` all immutable. Instead of using setters, you would be creating new instances of these types. And since you are working with such deeply nested data, you'd need a *lot* of effort to do this.

Comment: Why?  Streams are supposed to make your coding easier.  But why replace working code with a potentially less efficient stream solution.  Streams incur quite a bit of overhead to do what they do.

Comment: Why are you using a manual `Iterator` loop instead of for-each? If `getBatchEntryDetails()` does not return an `Iterable`, i.e. a `Collection`, it’s important to include the actual type in the question. Besides that, what does `detail.setAmount(detail.getAmount());` do? It looks like an entirely redundant operation.

Comment: @Sweeper no what is forbidden is structural modification of a stream (aka removing elements from the source for example), not modifications of individual elements of a stream.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I know. I didn’t say it was forbidden. It’s just unsuitable.

Comment: I concur with the 'leave it alone' approach.  Why rewrite working code into an unsuitable form?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem to stream your code is the use of the counter and the log.
Anyway a simple/readble solution would be not to stream from the beginning.
Something like this should work (can't test obviously):

```
AtomicInteger cntr = null;

Consumer<AchBatchEntryDetail> setCompany = d -> { int c = cntr.IncrementAndGet(); d.setReceivingIndividualCompanyName("Client Name"+c); log.info("Masked detail record #{}", c); };
Consumer<AchBatchEntryDetail> setAmount =  d -> d.setAmount(d.getAmount());
Consumer<AchBatchEntryDetail> setAccount = d -> d.setDfiAccountNumber(randomizeAccountNumber(d);
for (AchBatch batch : batches) {
    cntr = new AtomicInteger(); // new counter on each batch
    batch.stream()
         .map(AchBatch::getBatchEntries)
         .flatMap(Collection::stream)
         .map(AchBatchEntry::getBatchEntryDetails)
         .forEach(setCompany.andThen(setAmount).andThen(setAccount));
}
```